# Cosine Similarity of Eigen Vectors of two different matrices

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvector, cosine-similarity

Is it a valid measure, to find the cosine similarity of the Eigen vectors of two very large matrices, to compare how similar they are?

I have two very large matrices A and B. I found:

-> Co-Variance matrices C<sub>A</sub> and C<sub>B</sub>,

-> Top 20 Eigen vectors of C<sub>A</sub> and C<sub>B</sub>,

-> Cosine Similarity between the top 20 Eigen vectors.

Is it right to conclude, based on the cosine values, that the matrices A and B are similar/dissimilar?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, you certainly have to consider also the eigenvalues.

If you think a square N-by-N matrix as a linear operator that maps N-vectors into N-vectors, the action of the matrix on such vector spaces is strongly affected by the entire spectral structure of the matrix: eigenvectors and associated eigenvalues.

The largest eigenvalues are usually the most important, because they represent the directions in the N-vector space to which the matrix is more sensitive (eigenvectors).

In a good case scenario, the spectrum of a large matrix (i.e. the set of its eigenvalues) is well separable into a few largest eigenvalues and whole lot of small ones. In this case, it is possible to define a measure of similarity based on such set of dominant eigenvalues and associated eigenvectors.

To make an example from my own experience, for matrices arising from the modelling of elastic structures this is indeed the typical case, because the dominant eigenvalues/eigenvectors 'condense' the overall properties of the elastic structure.

This being said, there is no limit to how worse an pathological a specific case can be.
It depends very much on the specific problem under consideration, and in my opinion a confident assumption of 'matrix similarity' is very much driven by the physical insight
on the problem.

Other popular criteria to define 'similar' matrices are based on *singular value decomposition* (SVD), or *principal component analysis* (PCA).

Comment: A bit late to the party but +1 for the answer. Could you elaborate a bit more on the last sentence? Do you mean SVD or PCA can be used for such a comparison? If yes then how?

Comment: You could use the singular values instead of the eigenvalues.

Comment: I have a similar goal. I have 2 sets of the first 200 leading eigenvectors for 2 different matrices (A,B).  Is it valid to use cosine similarity on the sets of eigenvectors? I was thinking to take the frobenius norm of the cosine similarity matrix after excluding the diagonal, as a metric of error / dissimilarity ....